# Number inputs and ranges valueUpdate in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I've been working on a project I need a number input and a slider see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Dt7Ka/116/

```
<h2>Slider Demo</h2>

RAM: <input type="number" data-bind="value: ram,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: {max: 8192, min: 512, step: 1}" />
<div style="margin: 10px" data-bind="slider: ram, sliderOptions: {min: 512, max: 8192, range: 'min', step: 1}"></div>
```

In the case where someone want to manually enter a number (say 2048) I find that knockout goes into overkill and prevents me from entering 2048 correctly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

It's because you have `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` set. This causes the binding to try to update every time a key is pressed, and since you have a min of `512`, trying to enter a value of `2` is going to fail.

You can't enter `2048` because it tries to update after the first key. If you just take our that part of the binding it will work fine.

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: ram, attr: {max: 8192, min: 512, step: 1}" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dt7Ka/118/

Comment: Yes I am aware of this already, but the point of that was to provide real time update to the slider. If I remove that then they would have to click away from the number input for the slider to update.

Comment: Well, that's the issue. You can't have something update instantly *and* wait until you are finished typing to evaluate. You have to pick.

Comment: If you are looking for something in the middle, you could use a writable computed observable with a throttle, but that's a work-around.